# How to interpret CME's specification regarding grains options expirations?

Tags: options, commodities, cme

Looking at the contract specifications for [Soybean Meal](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/soybean-meal_contractSpecs_options.html#prodType=AME) and [Soybean Oil](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/soybean-oil_contractSpecs_options.html#prodType=AME) (same for [Corn](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/corn_contractSpecs_options.html), [Wheat](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/wheat_contractSpecs_options.html#prodType=AME), and other major stuff I checked) serial options on CME I see the following expiration rule:

> the last Friday which precedes by at least two business days the last
>   business day of the calendar month... If such Friday is not a business day, then the last day
>   of trading in such option shall be the business day prior to such
>   Friday.

However, for [Soybeans](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/soybean_contractSpecs_options.html), it states:

> The last Friday which precedes by at least two business days the last
>   business day of the month preceding the option month.

This is a bit confusing as it may suggest that expiration should be transferred to the previous Friday week back, rather than one day back (in case of holiday). As it is now, it states that the expiration is Friday (and not any other day would do). Since all other contract specifications have matching descriptions, I find it strange that this one is different. So, is it merely a slightly clumsy statement of the same rule, or the expiration dates for Soybean options are different for some reason?

I was unable to find expiration data for months when the would-be-expiration falls on holiday, which are December 2010 and 2015.